# Magento 2: How to Call a Console Command from a Custom Cron job?

Tags: magento2, cron, command

I'm working on a custom Cron and I want find the best way to call other commands from the Cronjob code in magento2 (programmatically).

For example:
When running cli "php bin/magento cache:clean" and so on or my custom console commands.

I try this code but, it is not work..

```
namespace AmirHome\Cron;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
...    
$arguments = new ArrayInput(['command' => 'my:custom:command']);
$this->getApplication()->find('my:custom:command')->run($arguments, 
$output);

$arguments = new ArrayInput(['command' => 'cache:flush']);
$this->getApplication()->find('cache:flush')->run($arguments, $output);
```

> Error: Call to undefined method AmirHome\Cron\MyCode::getApplication()

Answer (score 2):

- You need to add your custom console command to OS crontab.

  `crontab -u <Magento file system owner username> -e`

  For example,

  `crontab -u magento_user -e`
- Then add your commands with time interval in the end of the file as save,

  `* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento your_command:your_sub_command`

  For example,

  `* * * * * php /var/www/html/mysite/bin/magento myproduct:updateprice`

  Here, `* * * * *` is the time interval for every minute.

  - CRON_1MINUTE = '* * * * *';
  - CRON_5MINUTES = '*/5 * * * *';
  - CRON_10MINUTES = '*/10 * * * *';
  - CRON_15MINUTES = '*/15 * * * *';
  - CRON_20MINUTES = '*/20 * * * *';
  - CRON_HALFHOURLY = '*/30 * * * *';
  - CRON_HOURLY = '0 * * * *';
  - CRON_2HOURLY = '0 */2 * * *';
  - CRON_DAILY = '0 0 * * *';
  - CRON_TWICEDAILY = '0 0,12 * * *';

For references,

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html
- https://crontab.guru/